# Trying to do fragment navigation but android studio wants to reference a file that doesn't exist

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

the file name is IslandListFragment.kt and its partner is fragment_island_list.xml of course

unless i'm mistaken, the code should be

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_island_list, container, false)
```

but instead of

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_island_list, container, false)
```

android studio wants me to use

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_island_name, container, false)
```

fragment_island_list exists, fragment_island_name does not exist and trying to run this code in either form crashes the app.

any idea what i am missing here?

Comment: Try File->Invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try File->Invalidate caches/restart